# How to overwrite windowSoftInputMode using edit-config tag in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I'm trying to set windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan using cordovas [edit-config](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) tag in my config.xml (shortened):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.tillsanders.test" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
...
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:windowSoftInputMode]">
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    </edit-config>
...
</widget>
```

However, when building for android, I get this error message:

`Missing 'name' key attribute on element activity at AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-11:20`

Comment: You don't specify the actual Activity which needs that `android:windowSoftInputMode`

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Ahh, I understand! My previous attempts accidentally removed my `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular `AndroidManifest.xml` we declare activities one by one. That being said, if you have `Activity A` and `Activity B`, we want to declare it like the following:

```
  <activity
      android:name="A" />
  <activity
      android:name="B" />
```

Let's say we want the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for `Activity A`, then we can write it as follows:

```
  <activity
      android:name="A"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

You need to figure out the name of your `Activity` and declare it in the config.

Comment: With your help, I was able to get it working. I adjusted my config.xml to include this: `<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']"><activity android:name="MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" /></edit-config>`